# Socket.io.client not listening in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io

I have a Angular 12.03 project with socket.io.client version ^4.4.1.  The server is node.js with socket.io version ^4.4.1 and @socket.io/redis-adapter version ^7.1.0. Emitting from the client is clearly captured from the server.  The same message is meant to be relayed to angular listening to the event.  There is no error when the message is being emitted to listening client.  However the client does not seem to capture the sent message.  Note that this set up was working ok earlier but stoped working for no obvious reasons.

- running on node v14.15
- Using mac operating system

On the server, I have this line to handle push to individual clients:

```
io.to(socketId).emit(emittEvent, pushData)
```

When the server is running on debug, I can clearly see the data being sent with the right event.  Below is excerpt:

```
socket.io-redis publishing message to channel socket.io#/#-DNdSthj2lcvwHGMAAAL# +2ms
socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["push-menu",{"m":[{"label":"cd_geo",...
socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["push-menu",{"m":[{"label":"cd_geo",...
engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["push-menu",{"m":[{"label":"cd_geo",...
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +4ms
engine:ws writing "42["push-menu",{"m":[{"label":"cd_geo",...
socket.io-redis ignore same uid +10ms
engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +5s
engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nw20hvu" +0ms
engine handshaking client "47xo4baBGK3qIWodAAAM" +0ms
engine:transport readyState updated from undefined to open (polling) +5s
engine:socket readyState updated from undefined to opening +339ms
```

On the client side (Angular), I have the following service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EnvConfig } from '@corpdesk/core/src/lib/base';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketIoService {
  socket: any;
  readonly url: string = '';
  constructor(
    @Inject('env') private env: EnvConfig,
  ) {
    this.url = `${this.env.HOST}:` + this.env.SOCKET_IO_PORT;
    console.log('core/SocketioService::constructor()/eventName:', this.url)
    this.socket = io(this.url);
  }

  listen(eventName: string) {
    console.log('SocketioService::listen()/01')
    console.log('SocketioService::listen()/eventName:', eventName)
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      this.socket.on(eventName, (data: any) => {
        console.log('SocketioService::listen()/this.socket.on()/eventName:', eventName)
        console.log('core/SocketioService::listen()/this.socket.on()/data:', data)
        subscriber.next(data);
      });
    });
  }


  emit(eventName: string, data: any) {
    console.log('core/SocketioService::emit()/01')
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data, function (state:any) {
      console.log('core/SocketioService::emit()/02')
      console.log('core/SocketioService::emit()/state:', state)
      if (state.error) 
        console.log('Something went wrong on the server. ServerError:', state.error);
      if (state.ok)
        console.log('Event was processed successfully');
    });
  }

}
```

The component is consuming the service as below:

```
pushSubscribe() {
    console.log('SidebarComponent::pushSubscribe()/01');
    this.svSocket.listen('push-menu')
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('SidebarComponent::pushSubscribe()/data:', data);
        });
}
```

I hope someone can advise some way out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You subject and subscribe it inside components. And when you receive value from io.on then send value to subject using subject.next so now you do not need to wrap listen method inside observable . Do this change may be it works

Comment: Thanks @GaurangDhorda for your input. As  I am still trying your suggesion, note that the codes have been working before.  Additionally, on the service, I had put console.log('SocketioService::listen()/this.socket.on()/eventName:', eventName)
 just beneth the io.on to see if the event is being captured. The 'listening' is not responding to the server push at all.

Comment: socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
  // ...
}); Check this to see if you have any connection error or not

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, you can see from the logs that the connection, is available and socket is valid.  You can also see that the reidis adaper is also working ok. I am currently trying to check compatibility issues eg versions for server and client, node version, npm for installations including switch of os.

Comment: @goremo did you solved this ? if yes please tell me

Comment: @chiragsorathiya unfortunately, I have not found a solution yet.